# jsonnet : provide function to merge multiple objects into a single object

Tags: jsonnet

With jsonnet, I have multiple objects, and want to merge those into a single object. I know, that I can use the  '+' operator to merge objects. But I do not know how to apply this operator to a list of objects.

Specifically, I want to provide a function, which merges an arbitrary number of objects.
The objects can be provided as list items, or as dictionary fields.

My usecase is to provide application configuration, merged from a hierarchy of sources.

My current approach is:

- provide all objects as list items
- use comprehension to merge list items

Example:
This is my initial config object, with N nested objects:

```
local config = {
  conf1: { key1: 'val', foo: 'bar' },
  confN: { keyN: 'val', foo: 'baz' }
}
```

I want to merge the nested N objects into a single object, result should be:

```
local merged_config = {
  key1: 'val',
  keyN: 'val',
  foo: 'baz'
}
```

I tried to transform the initial object into a list of objects, and use a comprehension to merge the objects:

```
# get array of nested objects
local values = std.objectValuesAll(config),

# init merged config
local merged_config = {}

# use comprehension to merge objects
{
  merged_config: merged_config + x
  for x in config
}
```

But here I am stuck. I try to use a comprehensions as for-loop, but cannot get this to work. Probably this is the wrong approach.

Is there a better apporach then using a comprehension here?
Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with comprehensions under this context is that you can't duplicate a key, i.e. below code would *only* work if there are no dups (`foo` in your example):

```
{
  [k]: mainVal[k]
  for mainVal in std.objectValues(config)
  for k in std.objectFields(mainVal)
}
```

BTW besides the possible solution I provide here below, keep in mind that you're relying on the *sort* *order* of the "main" object keys (fields), which is not guaranteed when visiting objects' fields (that's why there's a `std.sort()` below)

The solution uses [std.foldl()](https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html#foldl) over the array of config fields (`conf1` ... `confN` in your case), to *aggregate* their values (and ok to override them).

### source

```
local config = {
  conf1: { key1: 'val', foo: 'bar' },
  confN: { keyN: 'val', foo: 'baz' },
};

// Loop over config's keys, aggregating their values
std.foldl(
  function(agg, key) agg + config[key],
  std.sort(std.objectFields(config)),
  {},
)
```

### output

```bash
$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet
{
   "foo": "baz",
   "key1": "val",
   "keyN": "val"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the hint to std.foldl , and good point that order of dict keys is not guaranteed.